# Emboss Mask Filter not working

Tags: android

I designed a custom view (highly inspired from catch notes application's circuler menu). The custom view is completed. The only problem I am facing in my project is that emboss mask filter is not working in my device. I tested the view on Android 2.3.3 emulator, Android 4.2 emulator and Bluestacks. In every single of them, emboss mask filter was working fine but on my device I am not able to see any light adjustment on the view I have designed. I am enclosing the screenshot for Android 2.3.3, Android 4.2 and My phone. If there is some issue with device like phone manufacturer will, Is there any replacement for Emboss Mask Filter ? I dont see why I need to put my code here. As it is working on all emulators.

[image: Emulator 2.3.3 ! Working Emboss Mask Filter]
[image: Jelly Bean Emulator 4.3 ! Working Emboss Mask Filter]
[image: My Phone Android 4.0.4 ICS ! Not Working]

Any clues ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that setting the target version below 13 fixed it.  14 and up failed to show it.

```
android:targetSdkVersion="13"
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that emboss mask filter is not available on hardware accleration. It was the issue with my device. However, to make emboss mask filter work with device, I had to disable hardware aceeleration for my view and set it to software layer. There are two ways to do it.

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Works for API > 10.
Another way.

```
android:layerType
```

in layout file.